# In what scope should I put a utility singleton component?

Tags: coldfusion, scope, coldfusion-10

We've just upgraded to CF10, and I'm finishing up a library of "missing" utility functions (mostly iteration-related, like `map` and `reduce`). These functions should always be available on every page and in every component in the application. They are methods of a stateless component that's basically acting as a module or namespace.

I have taken after Underscore and its ilk by referring to the component as `_`. So, usage looks like `_.map(myArray, myCallback);`. My question is where I should put the `_` variable. I can start every page with `variables._ = new Shared.Components.Util.FunctionalUtil();`, but that's annoying and we're going to end up with a lot of useless copies. I'd like to have it declared globally and initialized no more than once per request.

ColdFusion's "global" scopes are: CGI, URL, Form, Cookie, Client. These are the scopes used for name resolution that share their values across a request. Of these, the CGI, URL, and Form scopes run the risk of collision and the Cookie scope actually stores data on the client; this leaves Client. However, components cannot be stored in Client scope. In fact, the only ones that seem to work are URL and Form, and Form doesn't always exist.

Now, stuffing a utility component into URL kind of seems like a questionable thing to do. Is there a saner alternative?

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way is initializing the static component once when the application starts and declare an alias (shorthand) for use in the page context.

```
// Application.cfc

public boolean function onApplicationStart() {

    APPLICATION.FU = new Shared.Components.Util.FunctionalUtil();

    return true;
}

public boolean function onRequest(required string targetPage) {

    VARIABLES._ = APPLICATION.FU;

    include ARGUMENTS.targetPage;
    return true;
}
```

You can now access your static component using `_.someFunction();`. Outside of the page context (e.g. in another component), use `APPLICATION.FU.someFunction();`.

Comment: Hmm. This is definitely cleaner than `URL`, although it requires an extra `var _ = APPLICATION.FU;` (or perhaps `this._ = APPLICATION.FU`) in a lot of places. Also, we haven't migrated to an Application.cfc yet, although that's at the top of the when-we-have-time list.

Comment: If you're still using `Application.cfm` then it's super easy.  Just `<cfinclude>` the UDFs at the top and the UDFs will be in your variables scope at your target `.cfm`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the REQUEST scope or the APPLICATION scope. The application scope is the typical choice as it is "write once read many" - in other words, after you init your library it is available everyone and doesn't need to be reinited.

Comment: FYI - CF is replete with iteration functions of various kinds. Don't waste time trying to do things the way you are _used to doing them_ learn the CF way and bobs your uncle. :)

Comment: I don't have many objections to the built-in iteration functions, but they are woefully incomplete. There's an Each and a Filter, but no Map, Reduce, Every, Some, Group, and so forth. Without these functions, "the CF way" is a pile of extra code.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer should be `application` scope, but I have seen codes that used `form` or `url` scope to get away with specifying the scope name explicitly.

Comment: Misusing these scopes relies on the fact that the CFML engine inspects other scopes when omitting the variable scope to find the declaration. That's something that should not be recommended.